# RHEL6 Upstart: Flow of Events During Reboot

Tags: rhel6, upstart

I have a situation where a RHEL 6.4 server is sending `TERM` and `KILL` signals too quickly, before applications and databases have had a chance to gracefully stop.  It seems that Upstart is handing control to the sysv-rc scripts prematurely.

To troubleshoot this, I've tried adding `sleep` and `logger` commands into the Upstart config.  The `pre-script` stanza is writing to syslog, but the sleep never completes because the system reboots within 10 seconds.  I've also added a `kill timeout` which is ignored.

```
# cleanup at system shutdown
# Does stop all on apps, stops monit instances, then does a clean.
start on runlevel [016]

console output
kill timeout 120

task

pre-start script
    logger -s -t "arcsight-services-stopall" "Running pre-start..."
    /etc/init.d/arcsight_services stop
    sleep 60
end script

script
    logger -s -t "arcsight-services-stopall" "Running script..."
    /etc/init.d/arcsight_services shutdown monit
    /etc/init.d/arcsight_services clean all
end script
```

I know Upstart was suppose to parallelize the boot/halt process, but it has only paralyzed my debugging attempts.

**Under RHEL 6, what is the definitive order of scripts that get executed after issuing:** `shutdown -r now`**?**

1. `shutdown -r now`
2. `?????`
3. `/etc/init/rc.conf` (Upstart)
4. `/etc/rc.d/rc` (sysv-rc)
5. `?????`
6. `/etc/rc3.d/K*` (sysv-rc)
7. `/etc/rc6.d/S*` (sysv-rc)
8. `?????`

Where do the other /etc/init/*.conf scripts get called?

UPDATE:  In dissecting `/etc/rc.d/rc`, I found that if I `touch /var/run/confirm`, the process enters an interactive mode and then my sleep & logger commands seem to execute.  This baffles me, because I thought, at that point, Upstart has passed control to sysv-rc.

Comment: Don't write upstart scripts on RHEL 6. They are not supported (even though it actually uses upstart). Use a SysV style init script instead.

Comment: HP ArcSight Developers, are you reading this?  "Don't write upstart scripts on RHEL 6."  Thanks @MichaelHampton.

Comment: It's really just an unfortunate artifact of timing that RHEL ended up with Upstart at all. It was tried in Fedora and quickly abandoned since it was crap, but RHEL 6 went into feature freeze at just that time. [Virtually everyone else has abandoned Upstart, too](http://serverfault.com/a/518906/126632), and RHEL 7 uses systemd. That will last a little longer...

Answer (score 1):

While this answer doesn't address the order of scripts that get executed during a RHEL 6 shutdown, it does solve the issue of the system killing processes before they are gracefully stopped.

**/etc/init/arcsight-services-stopall.conf:**

```
# cleanup at system shutdown
# Does stop all on apps, stops monit instances, then does a clean.

start on starting rc RUNLEVEL=[016]

task
kill timeout 330

pre-start script
    logger -s -t "ArcSight" "ArcSight ESM shutdown initiated..."
    /etc/init.d/arcsight_services shutdown all
    /etc/init.d/arcsight_services shutdown monit
    /etc/init.d/arcsight_services clean all
    sleep 300
end script

script
    logger -s -t "ArcSight" "ArcSight ESM shutdown complete."
end script
```

The key was modifying `start on starting rc RUNLEVEL=[016]`.  By starting this script while `/etc/init/rc.conf` is just starting, it blocks for 5 minutes, before the sysv-rc scripts are executed.  Hopefully, during that 5 mintues, all the ArcSight databases and applications are gracefully stopped.  Testing indicated that everything was stopped within 3 minutes, so 5 minutes should be a safe delay.

It's always nice to see a multi-millon dollar product require a customer hack.